# MySQL Heavy Read operations on production database

Tags: mysql

```
MySQL running - 5.5.24
DB size: 3 tables with 200 M each
DB is running on AWS ec2 with 16GB RAM on server. 
8GB been allocated to MySQL.
```

As per expectation, write performance is fine:
100+ INSERT/sec, 100+ UPDATE/sec.

DB Parameters:

```
innodb_file_per_table | ON
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit | 2
innodb_flush_method | O_DIRECT
innodb_read_io_threads | 8
innodb_write_io_threads | 8
innodb_log_buffer_size | 33554432
innodb_log_file_size | 402653184
```

Issue: Suddenly, during checking

```
mysql> show engine innodb status\G
...
...
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue

1 read views open inside InnoDB

Main thread process no. 9924, id 140339369645824, state: sleeping

Number of rows inserted 1686580712, updated 1684027265, deleted 1681594351, read 66159327657

87.88 inserts/s, 88.21 updates/s, 87.77 deletes/s, **117894.90 reads/s**
```

We not expecting, 100K + reads/s? Is there an issue? What can we check?

Please suggest.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Though, with time it is showing some fluctuation:
81.23 inserts/s, 81.23 updates/s, 81.48 deletes/s, 132582.35 reads/s

60.79 inserts/s, 60.79 updates/s, 60.79 deletes/s, 261636.87 reads/s

75.42 inserts/s, 76.27 updates/s, 75.42 deletes/s, 115990.86 reads/s

71.79 inserts/s, 72.21 updates/s, 71.79 deletes/s, 55990.95 reads/s

..

Comment: I assume you backup your data, don't you?

Comment: We do backup our data from slave. The above stats is from master.